# Setting page specific header images with Jquery

Tags: php, jquery, html, css, wordpress

I have a Woocommerce store running on Wordpress.

There is the option for a header Image included in the "Trusted" theme which I am using and keen to use this option. It shows on every page, however, the header image is the same on all pages.

I would like to have a default image which shows on the home page and on any pages where there is no image specified.

I am able to specify images for each category page on Woocommerce and each brand page using Perfect Woocommerce Brands, however, these images are displayed below the header.

I am keen to find out if anyone knows how I would achieve what I am looking for, using JQuery.

Currently, the header image is displayed using CSS

```
.main-header{
    background-image:url(https://example.com/imageurl)
}
```

the category/Brand images are displayed via the HTML:

```
<div class="pwb-brand-banner pwb-clearfix">
    <img src="http://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/image.jpg" class="attachment-full size-full" alt="" srcset="http://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/image.jpg 1140w, http://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/image.jpg 300w, http://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/image.jpg 768w, http://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/image.jpg 1024w, http://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/image.jpg 600w, http://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/image.jpg 64w" sizes="(max-width: 1140px) 100vw, 1140px" width="1140" height="488">
</div>
```

So essentially, I would like to override the CSS that is setting the header image and set my own default image, then hook into the defined image for each category/brand and use that to replace the default image, unless no image is defined.

Any help on this would be great. I am ok with web design but I am beginner level with JQuery and cannot find anything online to help

The one thing I have found which looks similar to what I need (although I am unsure how to adapt it to my needs) is:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("header").on({
    mouseenter: function(){
        $(this).css("background-image", "url('/css/images/css.jpg')");
        },   
    });    
});
```

This changes the image on mouse enter Im looking for something of the sort:

```
If
    Image set via category/brand then use use set image
else
    use default ~ image $(this).css("background-image", "url('/css/images/css.jpg')");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (window.location.pathname != "/"){ // if it is not default page, replace the main-image background image with the category/brand image
    $(".main-header").css("background-image", 'url('+$(".attachment-full size-full").attr('src')+')');          
    // then probably hide the category/brand image
}
```

Comment: Thanks Raymond. Can I check, I have over 80 categories and brands. Would I need to set a different rule for each? Or is there a way to have it hook into the picture that has been set for that category/brand?